# Running gmail on chrome in a separate icon on docky?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, docky, gmail

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 with docky. I use Google Chrome as a default web browser. 
Is there any way that Docky has a separate launcher like "gmail" with the icon and when I click it, a gmail is launched on chrome-base just like any other mail client?

Sorry for my bad English.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, enter `google-chrome --app=http://gmail.com` then pin the icon (right click it then click 'Pin to Dock') for the window that appears.

`chromium-browser --app=http://gmail.com` is the equivalent command for Chromium.

This will work for other websites too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Chrome, I would suggest you to do the following to create an application shortcut for it.

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Login to your Gmail.
3. Click on 'Customize' (wrench icon) -> Tools -> Create application shortcut.
4. You will be asked to put the shortcut on Desktop or Application menu.
5. After that, you should be able to drag the logo into your docky. (Please verify this as I don't run a docky currenty)

Read [this link](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95710) for more info.

Comment: This approach works great for me, with Ubuntu 15.  I created desktop shortcuts.  I had to leave the shortcuts on the desktop for them to continue working in docky, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do this is to [download the Gmail Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia) and from the speed dial menu create a launcher for it. Then just drag it to Docky. This way, Gmail will open in a new window by default, but I'm not sure if Docky will rely on the Chrome or the Gmail icon in the window switcher (it works fine with AWN though).

Answer (score 0):

By installing the [GMail Docklet](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=GMail_Docklet) provided with Docky you are able to manage and open your GMail account using Chrome. In addition the Docklet checks and notifies for new mail and will show the number of unread mails on it's icon:

[image]